# Change Windows buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently making an application with Python. Is it possible to change the Windows buttons to the Apple theme? (only for this current app)

What I have:

[image: What I have - Screenshot]

What I want:

[image: What I want - Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the window controls are put there by the display manager, not your program.  If you want to do it the hard way, create a bare window with no decoration, then draw your own frame and control buttons.  You will have to wire the buttons to the right calls in your code.

To remove the border, you want

```
window.overrideredirect(1)
```

The controls will depend on what window manager is running.